# How to proper extract variables after getting it from Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, I am new to programming in general, not only kotlin/android/firebase. I hope my question makes sense.

After a get from firebase,I want to extract data from a field called "trust" to a variable called "trust" if the userId matches. I have managed to do it, but only if I use "If". I feel that there is a better way to do it.

I dont want to make another get because I dont want my app to make multiple database transaction if I already have the data locally available

```
db.collection("Users").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                  Log.d("DBTEST2", "${document.id} and ${document.data}")


                if(document.id == userStored) {
                  var trust = document["trust"]
                  Log.d("DBTEST3", "$trust")
      }
    }
        }.addOnFailureListener({ exception -> Log.w("DBTEST", "error", exception) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get a single document by its ID. The simplest way to do that is:

```
db.collection("Users").document(userStored).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
  if (document != null) {
    Log.d("DBTEST2", "${document.id} and ${document.data}")

    var trust = document["trust"]
    Log.d("DBTEST3", "$trust")
  }
}...
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: Thank you, Frank. In the end I think this document you linked was all I needed!! Have a great week!